# Return ActiveRecord relation from WHERE NOT EXISTS query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, activerecord-relation

Okay so here's a fun one. The relations are something like:

A `Client` `has_many` `state_changes`, and a `StateChange` `belongs_to` one `Client`.

I have this query: 
`Client.find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM clients cs WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM state_changes WHERE state_changes.client_id = cs.id AND current = true)')`

The problem is that this returns an `Array` object and not an ActiveRecord `Relation`. I need to run an update on the `state_changes` that belong to the returned `clients` from that query.

So there's two issues essentially, getting the results as an ActiveRecord relation, and then getting all of their `state_changes`, also as an ActiveRecord relation, so that I can run the update.

I also understand that this might be a convoluted way to go about it...

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: Yup I based my solution off of those scopes and it did as asked :) thank you

Comment: Ok, good to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also understand that this might be a convoluted way to go about it..

Having easy AR interface - indeed it is convoluted :)

I would probably go with some [`scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope)s:

```
class StateChange
  scope :active, -> { where.not(current: false) }
  # I believe with your setup it is not equal to `where(current: true)`
end

class Client
  scope :some_smart_name, -> { includes(:state_changes).merge(StateChange.active) }
end
```

This should return you clients who who don't have associated `state_changes` with `current` set to `false`.

Comment: Thank you for your swift response! What I'm actually trying to do is get all the clients that have no state changes that have the "current" bool attribute value of false.

Comment: I'll update my question to include that StateChange has a boolean field in the db called "current"

Comment: @barnacle.m Unless I'm missing something - updated answer should do the trick.